# AVURLAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo Return crash

Tags: ios, audio, video, avfoundation, avurlasset

I am woking with audio and video merge .
I am getting crash in

```
   [[AVURLAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0]
```

because of empty array AVURLAsset tracksWithMediaType.

I set .mp4 to .mov still its not working.

Following is the code

```
  NSURL *video_url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[UserDefaultsClass getVideoFile]];
  NSLog(@"video_url:%@",video_url);

 videoAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc]initWithURL:video_url options:nil];
 CMTimeRange video_timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero,audioAsset.duration);

 AVMutableCompositionTrack *a_compositionVideoTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
```

Here i set fileURLWithPath: still its not working.

In console video_url print :
 video_url:file:///Users/indecommglobal/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/35638854-89D1-429A-A01F-994A34F4E8B3/data/Containers/Data/Application/B5E2DA7E-E8F6-4078-B584-A0335FEEA84F/Documents/RecordedVideo/output03.mov

Really appreciated your help.
Thanks.

Comment: What is the exact error message or error-code you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Check video is present at particular path and run proper .

In my case,video is present at path ,but not able to run .
This mostly happen because video not write properly at that path.
Hope it helps.